# How to input a discontinuous range into SUMIF in Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, sumifs

I'm trying to do a SUMIF in Google Sheets, however since my input is a discontinuous range, it gives me an error. I am looking for a solution that does not require a Google Apps Script.

Works fine:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A9, "<>N/A")
```

Doesn't work:

```
=SUMIF(A1,A3,A7, "<>N/A")
```

Is there any method for doing a SUMIF with a non-continuous range as in the above non-working example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try like this:

```
=SUMIF({A1; A3; A7}, "<>N/A")
```